# Setter/Getter in protocol in swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

branchID is set to be a getter BUT I am able to set the value. What is the use of specifying it to be a setter/ getter?

```
    protocol Bank {
    var name: String {get set}
    var branchID: Int {get}
}

struct Person: Bank {enter code here
    var name: String = "ABC Bank"
    var branchID: Int = 123
}

let person = Person()
person.name
person.branchID
```

Comment: The protocol says that the type must *at least* support the operation; not that it is *limited* to only those operations. For this, Getters and Setters can be roughly considered two different methods that share the same name: ie. `Int get_branchId()` is required for the protocol; this does not *preclude* a `set_branchId(Int)`. However, if the code was to use a `Bank`-typed expression/variable, as opposed to a `Person`-typed expression as it does now via the `person` variable, the setter in Person would not be visible.. while the getter in the Bank protocol (which Person fulfills) would be.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code doesn't use the protocol.

If an object adopts a protocol it must implement the protocol requirements. Your code creates an object `Person` with all capabilities of `Person`

```
var person = Person()
```

and you can change `branchID`

```
person.branchID = 13
```

However if you cast `person` to `Bank`

```
var bank = person as Bank
bank.branchID = 13
```

you will get the error

> Cannot assign to property: 'branchID' is a get-only property

The same error occurs if you declare a function which tries to update all objects which conform to `Bank`

```
func updateID(item : Bank)
{
    item.branchID = 12
}
```

Comment: Thanks! much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

branchID in Person is a new object,You can certainly change its value.
when you write 'Bank. branchID',you can't set its value

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.